# How to hide menu elements in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-menu

I need to trigger a function on clicking the menu icon, and I don't need to show any items inside the menu. When I tries to avoid all the items inside the menu tag, the whole icon itself gets invisible. So **how could I display only the menu icon and hide its sub items?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

      //removing the above item removes the whole menu title icon.
    </menu>
```

Comment: you need a simple button not menu..!!

Comment: i can't add that on top right of action bar. It appears just after the action bar title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `app:showAsAction="always"`, as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu >
```

check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: isnt this helpfull@Hari Krishnan

Comment: You saved my day. THANKS A LOT ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Either use visible = false

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
android:title="Settings"
android:visible=false
app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Or Use a Toolbar inside which add a Menu icon and set onCLickListener().